# LONG POST Looking for Advice from those with Experience

Tags: career-development, student

I’m 24 years old and just started my final year of college pursuing an IT degree. As the days to graduation count down I’m starting to get anxious about my lack of plan for the future. I’m overwhelmed and under informed about all the options available to me as far as career paths go.

I’ve been working for an MSP with about 8 clients(roughly 350 users) as a “Technical Support Analyst” (Helpdesk) for 9 months now. I do a lot of M365 admin stuff, machine setups, knowBe4 admin, some reporting, lots of remoting in and helping users of course, and on the rare occasion some network setups.It’s been great experience and I am learning and enjoying the process but I also know that I want bigger and better things once I graduate, or even before then if an opportunity arises.

I’m looking for advice on what steps I need to take and what steps I should avoid on my way to creating a successful IT career. The problem is that I don’t really know what I enjoy about IT specifically. I enjoy planning things out and implementing them, and the problem solving that comes with that, but I think that encompasses most of what IT is.

How does one decide between security and networking? How do you know the steps to get to a DevOps role or even if you’d be good at it? It’s all just so overwhelming but since I’m graduating later than most of my peers I want to start trying to get a step ahead and get my career off to a great start.

I wish I could articulate my thoughts and concerns better but that’s something I struggle with. If you have any words of wisdom or advice please let me hear it, it will be great to hear from people who may have been in a similar position at my age/ point in life.

TLDR: I’m graduating with an IT degree in a year and I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: VTC - This is essentially a 'What career choice should I make' - we can't answer that for you. We can answer questions about the workplace such as how to deal with management or other employees - but we can't advise you on your career choice.

Comment: This post isn't even very long compared to others on this site.

Answer (score 3):

You apply for jobs that look interesting and that you have some of the qualifications for.  You interview with the ones that ask you for interviews, and determine if they still seem interesting.  If a job is offered and it sounds interesting, you take it.  If it continues to be interesting, you stay with it.  If you don't like it, while still working, you start looking again.  You don't jump from job to job - if you don't like them, then unless it is truly toxic, try to stay at least 2 years or so, so future employers will still consider you.

Somewhere in all of that, you will figure out what you really like to do, what you're good at, and (or) what someone else will pay for you to do.

(BTW, I was on my 6th job with nearly 15 years experience before I figured out what really made me happy.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight thursday. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about it in terms of technology. The tech now is going to be outdated in 5-10 years anyway.

All the skills that you learn out side of googling (or blinging, or whatever) and critical thinking will probably change as you work.

The only things consistent in IT are that the tech is never the same (unless you are doing IT stuff for the government then its 60 years old, and awful) and people are the worst.

You will find most job satisfaction by getting a job with people that you like spending time with.

When you are job hunting, you are choosing who you are going to spend 33% of your time with (until you quit, are fired, layed off, or retire). Choose well.

**Ask questions**, try to find out if your future boss/ coworkers are people you would voluntarily choose to spend time with.

Comment: That's a great point about trying to find a place where you get along with the people since you spend so much time with them. Thank you!